# Not using boost bind

Tags: c++, linux, networking, boost, compilation

my project uses boost library, but I want to call bind() function from /usr/include/sys/socket.h . Compilation fails since compiler takes boost::find function instead of the one I want to use. Any ideas?
Thank you

Comment: Don't use `using namespace ...;`? Please show code and error message.

Comment: Yes, go and find whoever did "`using namespace boost`" and have a word with them. In the meantime, call `::bind`.

Comment: None.  Either don't use `using` at all, and refer to whatever you need always in the code (Example:  prefer `std::cout` over just `cout`) or, if you prefer the brevity, use `using boost::something` for each particular thing you need.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 possible solutions that I see:

1. Do not put `using namespace boost` in your code, but call `boost::bind( )` instead
2. Call bind from socket.h as `::bind()`

I would suggest solution 1 as preferable, and solution 2 as temporary if solution 1 is unacceptable for whatever reason.